# Query strings and update table with ID (identity) number from another table

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update, multiple-tables

I have multiple tables that associate with each other (foreign key) using the itemID. For example my main table has the string name for the program (i.e. Microsoft, Oracle, etc).

MainTable

```
ID |  ProgNAME | ProID |
------------------------
11 | Microsoft |       |
12 | Oracle    |       |
13 | Microsoft |       |
14 | Microsoft |       |
15 | Oracle    |       |
```

ProgramTable

```
ProgramID | ProgramName|
------------------------
     1    | Microsoft  |
     2    | Oracle     |
```

I want to query my ProgramTable for the associated value (identity) linked to the sting and then insert or update my MainTable with the associated value (identity) into the ProID field. So my end result will be the following:

MainTable

```
ID  |  ProgNAME  | ProID  |
---------------------------
11  | Microsoft  |   1    |
12  | Oracle     |   2    |
13  | Microsoft  |   1    |
14  | Microsoft  |   1    |
15  | Oracle     |   2    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE MainTable
    SET ProID = P.ProgramID
FROM ProgramTable AS P
WHERE MainTable.ProgNAME = P.ProgramName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE M
SET M.ProID = P.ProgramID
FROM MainTable M INNER JOIN  ProgramTable P
ON M.ProgramName = P.ProgramName
```

Or if its only two values you can do something like ...

```
UPDATE MainTable
SET ProID = CASE WHEN ProgramName = 'Microsoft' THEN 1
                 WHEN ProgramName = 'Oracle'    THEN 2
            END
```